# Read Twitter page from Java

Tags: java, url, twitter, urlconnection

I would like to read the content of a tweet from Java, by using the public link of that tweet, e.g.:

http://twitter.com/FoodRhythms/status/461201880354271232/photo/1

I am using the same procedure used for reading content from other types of pages:

```
String XMLstring = "";
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

String inputLine;

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
    XMLstring += inputLine;
in.close();
```

However, while with other pages this works, when reading from Twitter links the returned content is empty (the `BufferedReader` object does not contain any line).

Any hint on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are approaching the problem in unnecessary complicated way. You would use an HTML parser library, such as [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) to parse the URL of it's content.

An example would be as follows:

```
String url = "https://twitter.com/FoodRhythms/status/461201880354271232/photo/1";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Element tweetText = doc.select("p.js-tweet-text.tweet-text").first();
System.out.println(tweetText.text());
```

which would output

```
Miso-Glazed Japanese Eggplant
```

In a similar fashion, you can select any element you want!

Answer (score 0):

Reading from twitter requires oAuth authentication, you will need to adhere to the twitter for java library to get the required data.

Hope this helps..!

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/03/twitter-api-on-your-java-application.html

Comment: I have it, since I am currently drinking tweets from the firehose. However, it is not clear to me how to read the URL content when the OAuth is available. As only reference to the tweet I have just that URL. How to use it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code right now is that you are trying to access twitter via http where an implicit redirect to https is happening. Using your exact code, modify the url to be https and all should work fine.